# Arduino LED lamp circuit

Tags: led

I am working on a RGB LED lamp project and this is the schematic for the circuit I managed to come up with.

[image: my led lamp circuit]

I am planning to integrate a 27V power supply that powers both the Arduino and a Bluetooth HC-05 module, so I calculated the required resistor values as seen on the schematic. Would this design work? Is 27V too much for the Arduino or does the LED setup balance everything out?

EDIT:

I made an attempt to fix my mistakes based on the answers I received here and this is the new schematic:

[image: new led lamp circuit]

This new model would use a 5V power supply instead. Would this fix all issues?

Comment: I suggest you to read the usermanual or datasheet of microcontroller. 27V is way to high for the board to handle. You have to reduce it down to suitable voltage level using any voltage regulators. And about the LEDs, the board might not seem to provide enough power to run all LEDs together.

Comment: the Arduino pins are 5 V. it will work with one LED, but not with 6 in series. every LED drops around 2 V so after 2 LEDs there is not enough voltage and nothing will light up.

Comment: No, this will not work. An Arduino works at 5V and 27V will destroy it. You cannot control the LEDs directly from the Arduino's pins. You need a transistor or MOSFET based circuit to be able to control the LEDs from a lower voltage digital output pin. What current do these LEDs run at?

Comment: This is not a software question, it's an electrical one.  Read the datasheet.  And then learn Ohm's Law.

Comment: in the updated schematics every LED must have its own resistor usually at least 100 Ohm. it is better to have the transistor after the LEDs

Answer (score 1):

No. You will destroy the Arduino and the bluetooth module.

Firstly the Arduino needs no more than 20V absolute maximum - recommended no more than 16V.

Secondly a resistor is not a voltage regulator. It can only drop a fixed voltage when you have a fixed current. It only works with LEDs because they are themselves a fixed voltage.

Thirdly an Arduino output cannot power 6 LEDs in series. You get 5V out, but the combined forward voltage of 6 LEDs is between 12 and 18 volts depending on the colour.